# Laravel, restricting route parameter to table column values

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing

There are two routes of the same type

```
Route::get('/{category_slug}/{city_slug}/{state_slug}', 'PagesController@categoryByStateCity')->name('page.category.state.city');
Route::get('/{item_slug}/{city_slug}/{state_slug}', 'PagesController@item')->name('page.item');
```

category_slug - Category parameter
item_slug - Company parameter

They have the same structure, so this url

> /demo-company/city/state

will be processed by the first route as category

Is there an elegant solution to limit each of these parameters to their own values, right when building routing?

PS

> ->where('option1|option2|option3...)

The option is not suitable, since there can be 5000 values and a long string is obtained.

PS2 Maybe there is an opportunity to use Middleware

**Please note that I do not want to use a controller to check a parameter. I want to have different routes, and do it at the route level.**

Comment: So, basically you need to limit `category_slug` to the `slug` from the Category table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Route::pattern](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#parameters-global-constraints) to achieve this.

In `RouteServiceProvider` inside `boot` method you can use:

```
Route::pattern('category_slug', implode('|', $this->categorySlugs());
```

and implement `categorySlugs` method to return array of allowed slugs:

```
protected function categorySlugs()
{
  $allowedSlugs = [];

  // @todo implement
  // list all options here (probably not the best when you have 5000 options)
  // or load list from database/file

  return $allowedSlugs;
}
```